# Proof of a Caccioppoli inequality for non-symmetric operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators, functional-inequalities

I am reading the book Elliptic Partial Differential Equation by Fanghua Lin and I got stuck at the lemma 1.36 ( the Caccioppoli inequality). The conditions of this lemma are: $u\in C^1(B_1)$ ($B_1$ is the unit ball in $R^n$) satisfies $$\int_{B_1}\sum{a_{ij}D_iuD_j\varphi}=0 \forall \varphi\in C_{0}^1(B_1)$$

$a_{ij}\in C^1(B_1)$ satisfies
$$\lambda|\xi|^2\le\sum a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\le\Lambda|\xi|^2 \forall x\in B_1,\forall \xi\in R^n$$ where $\lambda,\Lambda>0$

In the proof of this lemma, the author set $\varphi=\eta^2u$ where $\eta\in C^1_0(B_1)$ and then he claims that

$$\lambda\int_{B_1}\eta^2|Du|^2\le \Lambda\int_{B_1}\eta|u||D\eta||Du|.$$

Can anyone prove the above inequality in the case $a_{ij}$ are not symmetric?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For those who do not have this book, can you edit your question (use the edit button) to add an explanation of the notation?  What are the functions $u, \eta$, what spaces do they live in, what is known about them?  What are $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$?  What is $B_1$?  I have a general idea of how to prove inequalities like this, but without knowing exactly what is being stated here, I am not sure.

Comment: I added some condition to my problem. Sorry for any ambiguity ! This is the first time I joint this website.

Comment: BTW: Cacioppoli, not Caccipoli!

Comment: Yes I missed one 'p'

Comment: Something seems to be wrong; perhaps a missing factor of 2?  If the operator is symmetric, i.e. $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ then I can use Cauchy-Schwarz but I get a factor of 2 on the right side.  Indeed I don't think it is true as written: if I take $n=1$ and $a_{11}=1$ so that $\lambda=\Lambda=1$, and take $u(x)=x$ and $\eta(x)=1-x^2$, I get $16/15$ on the left and $8/15$ on the right.

Comment: can you give me your proof ?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality seems to be false as written.  If we take $n=1$, so that $B_1$ is the interval $(-1,1)$, and $a_{11} = 1$ so that the ellipticity condition holds with $\Lambda = \lambda = 1$, and let $u(x) = x$ and $\eta(x) = 1-x^2$, then direct calculation shows that the left side of the desired inequality is $16/15$ and the right side is $8/15$.  (I am not sure whether $C^1_0(B_1)$ means "vanishes on the boundary" or "compactly supported in the open ball"; if it's the latter, then modify $\eta$ slightly with a cutoff function.  This will change both sides of the inequality only slightly, so it still fails.)

If you multiply the right side of the desired inequality by 2, then I can prove it in the symmetric case when $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$.  For vectors $\xi, \zeta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in B_1$, consider the symmetric quadratic form $q_x(\xi, \zeta) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}(x) \xi_i \eta_j$.  We have $q_x(\xi, \xi) \ge \lambda |\xi|^2$ so $q_x$ is positive definite.  Thus $q_x$ satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$|q_x(\xi,\zeta)| \le \sqrt{q_x(\xi,\xi) q_x(\zeta,\zeta)}.$$
But since $q_x(\xi, \xi) \le \Lambda |\xi|^2$ this implies
$$|q_x(\xi, \zeta)| \le \Lambda |\xi| |\zeta|. \tag{*}$$

Now if $u$ is a solution and we take $\varphi = \eta^2 u$, then we have
$$\begin{align*}0 &= \int q_x(Du, D[\eta^2 u]) \\ &= \int q_x(Du, 2 \eta u D\eta + \eta^2 Du) \\ &= 2\int  \eta u q_x(Du, D\eta) + \int \eta^2 q_x(Du, Du).\end{align*}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align*} \lambda \int \eta^2 |Du|^2 &\le \int \eta^2 q_x(Du,Du) \\
&= -2 \int \eta u q_x(Du, D\eta) \\
&= \left| -2 \int \eta u q_x(Du, D\eta) \right| \\
&\le 2 \int \eta |u| |q_x(Du, D\eta)| \\
&\le 2 \Lambda \int \eta |u| |Du| |D\eta|
\end{align*}$$ 
using (*) in the last line.

I am not sure how to handle the non-symmetric case.

Comment: In my problem, $a_{ij}$ is not symmetric and $\eta$ has compact support. Do you have the book of Fanghua Lin ?

Comment: The number 2 is not a problem. The final goal is to find a constant which depends only on $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$. I can see your idea. The Cauchy-Schwarz is only applied when we have a symmetric quadratic form.