# Proof of a Caccioppoli type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis

Can someone give me a proof for a Caccioppoli type inequality looking like
$$ \int_M |\nabla u|^2 \psi^2 \leq C \int_M u^2 |\nabla \psi| ^2 $$
where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold.

I have seen multiple times this inequality but I can't find a proof and I don't know what are the hypothesis. I also don't see how to prove it.

Comment: $u$ is a non-negative sub-harmonic function. ($M$ is compact?) and $C>0$.

Comment: [just related!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298052/272127)

Comment: You should state your assumptions on $u$.

Comment: If $u$ is harmonic, just use integration by parts and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Deane: As I said, I think $u$
  is a non-negative sub-harmonic function. does sub-harmonicity implies harmonicity?

Comment: @C.F.G, sorry. Subharmonicity suffices. I don’t think you need to assume $u$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality holds only if $u$ satisfies additional assumptions. The simplest is if $u$ satisfies $u\ge 0$ (my comment above was wrong) and
$$ -\Delta u \le 0. $$
Also, assume that $\psi$ is compactly supported. In that case,
\begin{align*}
\int |\nabla u|^2\psi^2 &= \int \nabla^i(u\psi^2\nabla_i u)- u\Delta u\psi^2 - 2u\psi\nabla\psi\cdot\nabla u\\
&\le  \int -2(u\nabla\psi)\cdot(\psi\nabla u)\\
&\le 2\left(\int u^2|\nabla\psi|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\int \psi^2|\nabla u|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\le 2\left(\delta^{-2}\int u^2|\nabla\psi|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\delta^2\int \psi^2|\nabla u|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\le \delta^{-2}\int u^2|\nabla\psi|^2 + \delta^2\int \psi^2|\nabla u|^2
\end{align*}
If we set $\delta$ to any positive value less than $1$, then we get
$$
\int |\nabla u|^2\psi^2 \le \frac{\delta^{-2}}{1-\delta^2}\int u^2|\nabla\psi|^2.
$$

Comment: How does the first inequality in the derivation is obtained ? Can u add explanation to your answer ? Thanks man ! Are u using something like $\int_M \nabla^i (u \psi^2 \nabla_i u) = \int_{\partial M}  (u \psi^2 \nabla_i u).dA = 0$ since  $(u \psi^2 \nabla_i u)|_{\partial M} = 0$ ? If so there is assumption that $(u \psi^2 \nabla_i u)|_{\partial M} = 0$ and to apply divergence theorem we need to assume some properties on $M$.

Comment: @Balajisb, I'm assuming that $M$ is a manifold without boundary. The assumption that $\psi$ is compactly supported means there is a compact set $K \subset M$ such that $\psi = 0$ on $M\backslash K$. You can replace $K$ by a larger compact set with smooth boundary. The integration by parts is done on $K$ and not $M$ (which has no boundary).

Comment: Thanks...so u need the property that the compact set $K$ which is support of $\psi$ is contained in a larger compact set with smooth boundary. Can this larger compact set be always found in $M$ for every $K$ ? If not pls state this assumption in the answer. Thanks man..I have already given you +1 :-)

Comment: You can of course embed $K$ in the interior of a larger compact set $K'$ by covering $K$ by set of small geodesic balls and taking the closure of the balls. It is not hard to use the distance functions from $K$ and $K'$ to define a Lipschitz function $\chi$ that is $0$ outside $K'$, $1$ on $K$, and between $0$ and $1$ on $K'\backslash K$, where the Lipschitz constant at each poin of $\partial K'$ is bounded away from zero. Now you can use a smooth function $\psi$ that is close to $\chi$ in the Lipschitz norm.